# Intellij change intention menu behavior to be more like netbeans

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea

I'm currently learning Intellij IDEA for Scala development, which is proving to be a smooth transitition with the Netbeans IDE keymap. However, the biggest difference I'm experiencing is the difference in the ways the two IDEs handle the intention menu (alt+enter menu).

Netbeans will always display a menu if the carat is on the same line as the issue, even if the carat isn't currently on the highlighted issue. Intellij, however, will only display this menu if the carat is positioned over the highlighted issue.

Is there any setting buried in Intellij that changes this behavior to be more like netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such setting. The Alt-Enter menu in IntelliJ IDEA shows both quickfixes and intention actions, and for almost every caret locations there are intention actions available, so it's not necessarily appropriate to show the menu for the error instead.

Note that you can use F2 (Goto Next Highlighted Error) to navigate to the error quickly, and then press Alt-Enter.